# Converting a string to float in Perl

Tags: string, csv, perl, floating-point

I'm new to Perl. I am reading a CSV file using Perl. The first column of the CSV is time (which is a float). I've read the CSV and displayed the contents of the CSV successfully. Further, I wish to use the CSV data for some computations.  I need the time column as an array (or any data structure). On reading the time column and storing it in an array, it is stored as a string. I wish to have a numeric array for arithmetic computations.

I've tried adding 0, mul 1 and then storing it in the array,using sprintf but i'm encountering errors.

```
use v5.30.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die;
open(my $data, '<',$file) or die;
my @timeArray;

while(my $line = <$data>){
    chomp $line;
    my @words = split ",",$line;
    #my $temp=$words[1]*1;
    my $temp=sprintf "%.6f",$words[1];
    push @timeArray,$temp;
}
```

Error:

```
Argument ""67.891947295"" isn't numeric in multiplication (*) at 3.pl line 12, <$data> line 19556.

and 

Argument ""67.840034174"" isn't numeric in sprintf at 3.pl line 13, <$data> line 19555.
```

Also, why is the argument in ""  "" .

Comment: You don't show your CSV file, but it looks like that field is quoted, and you're not removing the quotes. Use `Text::CSV_XS` if you want to read non-trivial CSV data, not `split`.

Comment: Could you please write the block for reading the CSV using Text::CSV_XS, I can't find any good resources.

Comment: There are examples in the documentation...

Comment: The problem isn't converting a string to a number, the problem is that the string you have isn't a number because you didn't properly parse the CSV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good idea to handle data like that with the proper module, because there are several important details that you didn't take care of. Examples:

- The columns values may be enclosed in quotes
- The first row may contain the header names of each column
- The last record in the file may or may not have an ending line break
- Etc.

Read the [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) document for more information.

There are lots of modules that can parse CSV format, for example: [Text:CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). It's very easy to install, and when you use it, your *string to double* problem will disappear.

Comment: Re "*It's very easy to install*", ...and use!